# How to Use Java Backend for Electron Js with Mysql Database(any) or Firebase?

Tags: javascript, java, electron, backend, desktop-application

I have created an Electron Desktop Application I need to make backend to insert data into the database and retrieve from database actually some CRUD operations but I know java well. how can I configure java with Electron js ?

Comment: You'd probably make normal rest/API calls to a Java back end. I'm not sure what else you have in mind.

Comment: Take a look at this sample application. https://github.com/electron/simple-samples/tree/master/prices  It downloads and parses a CSV file from a server (much like you're thinking), and parses it to display the results. It uses `papaparser.js` for the CSV work. So that is the desktop app part. For the server backend you can spin up a Spring Boot REST server in about 4 minutes for it to communicate with. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Said a different way, you can think of you Electron Desktop App in exactly the same way you think of a Browser. It is the client in the client/server arrangement you are asking about.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the Comment.  my application basically like History app so there will be two user rolls one is viewer another one is admin adding data and updating current data only for admin .. so I made that software using electron js and hardcoded only view part... so I needed the backend admin part  now for adding and updating option problem is I know only java so how can I integrate java with electron js to fill these requirements hope you understood my problem.Thanks

Comment: Why Java? Why not do the whole thing in Electron? In any case, what I said still stands.

Comment: we can't do backend with electron I guess we need some language to connect data manipulation